# wp_deregister_script was called incorrectly

Tags: theme-development, javascript, theme-options, wp-register-script

So apparently I am now allowed to do the following in the admin, ON my theme options page and only ON my theme options pages:

```
public function load_admin_jquery(){
    if(isset($this->_options['admin_jquery_version'])){
        wp_deregister_script ( 'jquery' );
        wp_register_script ( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/'.$this->_options['admin_jquery_version'].'/jquery.min.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script ( 'jquery', true, true );             
    }
}
```

Can some one explain why? I am only setting the new version of jquery ON my theme options pages ONLY

The exact error is:

> Notice: wp_deregister_script was called **incorrectly**.
>   Do not deregister the `jquery` script in the administration
>   area. To target the frontend theme, use the
>   `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook. Please see Debugging in
>   WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version
>   3.6.) in /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2986

I have Twitter bootstrap loading in my theme options page and I would like to be in control of the jquery version being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All other scripts running on that page depend on the correct jQuery file shipped with WordPress: admin bar, jQuery-UI or other plugins.

Note that loading external resources is not possible in all setups, so your options page would not work in these cases.

To use scripts that needs `$` use `$ = jQuery.noConflict();` or put it into a wrapper.

Comment: >.> this is redic.